# How to show that this set is not algebraic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to show that the set:
$$ Z=\{ (\cos t ,\sin t, t) | t \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
is not algebraic?

Thank you

Comment: What are your thoughts? What is the definition of being algebraic?

Comment: Algebraic that is zero set of a polynomial or of a set of polynomials.

Answer (score 4):

If you restrict to the line $x=0, y=1$ then there's still a countable infinity of solutions. 
Which polynomials in one variable have infinitely many roots?